# How to simply print a page in Processing?

Tags: java, printing, dialog, processing

for my current project, I'm looking for a really simple workaround. I do a random graphic in Processing, and when the code has finished the graphic it should print on my printer. But preferable without the dialog etc. Just print it on paper.

I was looking around the Internet and several Java forums, but I only found "overkill" tutorials. (like this: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2000/jw-1020-print.html)

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Would saving a PDF from your sketch, then manually opening the file and printing be an option ?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about [GDSPrinting](http://gdsprinting.sourceforge.net/). While I've not used it and according to that page it's version 0.2, it may be a solution for you.

As has been said too many times before: Java and Printers don't get along very well.
I wish you luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a hack, but if you can't find what you're looking for, script taking a screenshot (keyboard command) and open a photo editor and print. http://sikuli.org/ can automate pressing buttons (like print) and you can execute external commands from Processing using open()

http://processing.org/reference/open_.html

http://sikuli.org/docx/faq/010-command-line.html

Answer (score 0):

If there is no easy way to directly call the printer, you may use the java Robot class, here is an example on how to use it: [How to simulate keyboard presses in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745959/how-to-simulate-keyboard-presses-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this 8 years late, but hopefully it helps anyone who finds this thread.

First save the image / frame that you want to print with a definite path:

```
save(“image_to_print.png”);
```

Then add this method to your sketch:

```
void printImage(String path) {  
  Process p = exec("lp", path); 
  try {
    int result = p.waitFor();
    println("the process returned " + result);
  } 
  catch (InterruptedException e) {
    println("error : " + e);
  }
}
```

Now just call the method with the relevant filename and path:

```
printImage("/Users/me/Desktop/printDemo/image_to_print.png");
```

It's the equivalent of running the following in your command line interface:

```
lp image_to_print.txt
```

Here's a [medium post explaining this](https://medium.com/@mithru/using-processing-to-print-your-sketches-25ce4d2ee8fe).