# How to simulate keyboard presses in java?

Tags: java, io

I want to run a java program and have it simulate keyboard presses.
So it could for example, type some text on a focused input box.
Is this possible?

Comment: The Robot class can do this for you, but if you want to do other more fancy interactions with an outside process, you may wish to use a different language as Java does not get very close to the OS by design.

Comment: You mean simulate keyboard presses on an input box of your own program, or from an other application ?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

**[java.awt.Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)** might help.

Here's a simple sample code snippet from [Java Tips](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.awt/simulating-mouse-and-key-presses.html):

```
try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        // Simulate a mouse click
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        // Simulate a key press
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);

} catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: If you need to achieve this while using JavaFX use FXRobot. The API is quite similar.

Comment: can we write on to another application using robot class? like a text box in another application that is running along with this.

Comment: How to pess two button simltaneously (like : ctrl+A or SHIFT+A) ?

Comment: @partho `robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_B);`

Comment: From Robot class javadoc "Note that some platforms require special privileges or extensions to access low-level input control. If the current platform configuration does not allow input control, an AWTException will be thrown when trying to construct Robot objects. For example, X-Window systems will throw the exception if the XTEST 2.2 standard extension is not supported (or not enabled) by the X server."