# Keyboard events out of my program JAVA

Tags: java, events, keyboard

I would like to make a program that detect when I press a key e.g. the key F1 and then write a password.
I manage a lot of password in my job and I would like to have and aplication like this.
The problem is that I don't know how to start.
I want to run the aplication and runs it in the background listening for all events of keyboard and, when the program detects the key F1 is pressed, put the password that i want in a textfield e.g. in google chrome.
I don't know if this is posible.
Thank a lot for your time!

Comment: I'm pretty sure its impossible for java to detect external system events, as its too higher level and sits in its own JVM. You'd be better off using c++/c#.

Comment: This answer may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745959/how-to-simulate-keyboard-presses-in-java

Comment: I will try the second option, the Robot class, this is not exactly that I want but maybe is a way to start... The option of c++ or c# no for the moment. Thank a lot!!!