# Simulating keyboard presses - Java

Tags: java

I am writing an application that needs to write test to wherever the user has the cursor placed within their desktop environment.

I am aware that I can accomplish this by simulating actual key presses with the Robot class; however, I am wondering if their is a more efficient way to do this.

Is there any System output that I could just write to so that I don't need to simulate *actual* keypresses? Any thoughts?

Comment: Related: [How to simulate keyboard presses in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7745959)

Comment: @jww That's where I got the idea to use a Robot class. My question is if I actually need to simulate an actual keypress.