# Highest performance for Keyboard Input

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, key-bindings

So I have a small java game engine using a single JFrame.

I am currently using Key-Bindings as they were working neatly but I figured that a KeyListener might be architecturally more fitting.

But since I honestly don't really care which I'll use I wanted to ask if there is a performance difference between these or even a better option for getting keyboard input.

Thank you lots for your help!

Comment: "*... I wanted to ask if there is a performance difference between these ...*" - Why not try it out?

Comment: Sure thing! How would you test it? I mean you can't really measure the time between key-press and the program registering the input... Do you have any tips?

Comment: question is: do you need hard numbers or does a subjective test suffice? If you need hard numbers, you could use a framework simulating key presses (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745959/how-to-simulate-keyboard-presses-in-java)) and log the exact time the key is pressed and then log the time at which your program processed the event.

Comment: I mean as I said I don't care which I use so just the general idea of which one works faster is sufficient for me, I guess I'd be best to setup both and let each print when they registered the key..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my consultation with Turing85 and some testing I figured out that the KeyListener is even up to 1ms faster than the binding.

==> If you go for performance KeyListener is your friend.